# How can I run an XBMC/Kodi video-plugin in python script?

Tags: python, add-on, xbmc, kodi

I am trying to develop an XBMC/Kodi addon and my goal is run script and plugins from python script. There are buttons in addon.py when you pushed them, the addon that specified will run. I achieved this for picture and game add-on. Like this:

```
if control == self.button1:
  xbmc.executebuiltin("RunScript(script.game)")
if control == self.button2:
  xbmc.executebuiltin("RunScript(script.picture)")
```

I tried this way to call video plugin, but give me some error message. When I searched this problem, I found this:

> "Do not try to run Plugins files from the scripts window as that will only give you a weird error message"

Is there an another way to call a video plugin from python script or can we a write a video-script instead of plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call video plugin as follow:

```
xbmc.executebuiltin("ActivateWindow(<window-id>,'plugin://<plugin-id>/<parameter-optional>',return)")
ex.
xbmc.executebuiltin("ActivateWindow(10025,'plugin://plugin.video.example/',return)")
```

from kodi 17 [window ID](http://kodi.wiki/view/Window_IDs) for video plugin is 10025

Comment: for me this method works for running script too. just you need to make sure that plugin or script is exist/installed and enabled

Answer (score 1):

You can also use **RunPlugin** and **RunAddon** which are the builtin Function of Kodi. (for detail refer this [KODI List of builtin Functions](http://kodi.wiki/view/List_of_built-in_functions))

Here is the example to run any plugin :

1. To run plugin use :   `xbmc.executebuiltin('RunPlugin("plugin.video.something")')`
2. To run script use :
   `xbmc.executebuiltin('RunAddon("script.something")')`

Comment: I tried your first example for plugin;give me some error and I found this information on Kodi's page you cant run plugin from python script ...

Comment: @LadyLyanna I think the method is deprecated though it was given in tutorial but you can also use second method that i had mention earlier .i.e, `xbmc.executebuiltin('RunAddon("plugin.video.something")')`